# Comic about two children who live on an asteroid

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I read this story recently but I am unable to find the story anywhere :-

- The story starts with 2 children wearing space suits on an asteroid and expertly unearthing what seems to them like the skeleton of a God.
- These children were actually on a spaceship with a guardian, but when on an 'expedition to explore the Asteroid the spaceship had landed on, he was hit by something and dies.
- When the on-board computer loses the life-signs of the guardian, he awakens the 2 children from cyro-sleep.
- These children however, have no memory of their pre-cyro lives. They are extremely intelligent however, and somehow manage to stay healthy by using the food onboard the spaceship and frequent space-walks.
- A human spaceship discovers their life-signs and 'rescues' them only to find that the two children are unaccustomed to anything a normal human would do and think that the other 'grown-ups' are actually gods.
- One of the children is a boy while the other is a girl.
- I have no idea if there was a sequel OR a prequel to this.
- I read this in a comic.
- It was an Indian production.
- I have no evidence of it being a translation, but it was in English.
- It was illustrated by a person called Indrapramit Das.
- It appeared in Tinkle.
- I ***think*** it was named 'Children of the Gods'. Not to be mixed up with the [book](https://www.google.com/search?q=children+of+the+gods&oq=children+of+the+gods&aqs=chrome..69i57j46l2j0j0i390.5222j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Roughly when would this have been published? Or at the very least, when did you read it and did it look new (for instance computer-drawn), or rather felt oldish?

Comment: @Jenayah, I read it somewhere between 2017-2019 and it was illustrated by hand, but it looked as if a computer had done it.

Comment: Based on your edit, are we to understand this is likely an Indian production? In which language did you read it in, any chance it was a translation?

Comment: @Jenayah, I don't remember it as a translation, but it was definitely in english. And it was, as you said, an Indian production.

Comment: http://indradas.com/writing/ might help

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, there is no mention in the site about any of his works with Tinkle. They are only his independently written sci-fi ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it!

The story was published in Tinkle Digest No. - 244 that was released on August of 2014. The story's name was "The Children of Gods", but for some reason cannot be found *anywhere* on the internet (feel free to insert a link here if you find it).

The story starts with 2 children wearing space suits on an asteroid and expertly unearthing what seems to them like the skeleton of a God. The next few scenes show them on board a spaceship examining the skeleton, when one of them says it resembles their own skeleton except it is several times their size. They realize that they are not alone in the universe. In a later part of the story it is told that it was the skeleton of the guardian who was killed.

Next they are shown playing 'Tag' with their space-suit thrusters in space, when another giant spaceship turn up and a adult comes out of it in a space-suit. Note that until this point they were the only beings shown. They exhibit their surprise when the other astronaut warns them that their space-suits are not toys, grabs them and brings them on-board their spaceship.

When the astronaut is doing so, they do not resist and instead ask him if he is a god to which he replies in the negative. On board the larger spaceship, they are in a room playing, when two adults outside the room are shown talking about them. One remarks that they had been woken up from cyro-sleep some time ago and had absolutely no memory of their pre-cyro lives. They were extremely intelligent, and managed to stay alive because of the food onboard the spaceship and frequent space-walks.

When the space-ship approaches Earth, the two children, who were in fact twins remark that they have a lot to learn about the Earth and it's inhabitants, and the story ends there.

This story was exclusively written for Tinkle and it does not (to my knowledge) have a sequel or a prequel.